# Pasting many files together in some sort of loop, paste command

Tags: unix, command-line, paste

I want to do something like

```
for i in (1..101)
do
     paste file${i}
done
```

But this would be 100 separate commands instead of pasting 100 files together

So that I don't have to do

```
paste file1 file2 file3 file4 ....... file101
```

Thank-you

Comment: You can concatenate the strings first and then run the command

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on that a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of running the command in the loop, you could concatenate the strings in the loop and then run the command at the end.

```
STR=""
for i in (1..101)
do
    STR=$STR"file"$i" "
done
paste $STR
```

Answer (score 0):

To paste 101 files numbered from 1 to 101, you can use the [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) feature of Bash and Korn Shell.

```
paste file{1..101} > output.file
```

Beware: the brace expansion notation is brittle — it does not take much to break it — and not very flexible (for example, the range can't be specified by variable).

You could also consider using `seq`:

```
paste $(seq -f 'file%.0f' 1 101) > output.file
```

That works as long as the generated names don't contain spaces or other similar characters.